# Output format not right in xAct

Tags: xact

I started using `xAct` to perform some computations. I copied the xAct folder in the /.Mathematica/Applications folder in my Ubuntu system. I loaded it and created the manifold and defined the metric. The output however is not coming right on using the ordinary derivative PD[].

```
PD[-a][PD[-b][T[c, d, -e]]]
```

Out: $PD(-a)(PD(-b)(T(c,d,-e)))$

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Also whenever I click the `xAct` option in the Addons page of Mathematica, the screen freezes. I am using Mathematica 10.

Comment: IN: PD[-a]@ PD[-b]@T[c, d, -e] is the correct command.

Comment: @SUMANKUNDU isn't it the same command?

Answer (score 1):

Format --> Option Inspector..." --> set "show option values" to "Global Preferences" --> type "OutputToStandardForm" in the search box and set the option setting to "True" ---> click on "Apply".

I believe this should work.

If the problem remains and you have Mathematica 11 then you can also try :   Edit-->Preferences-->Evaluation and set the "Format type of new output cells" to "StandardForm"